# Installing unpacked ruby gem

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-snow-leopard, cairo

I am trying to install the cairo ruby gem on OSX 10.6. There seems to be a bug in the extconf.rb, which I've patched, but now I don't know how to create a gem, so I can install it... `gem build folder` won't work because there is no gemspec file or whatever (I've got absolutely no experience with gems^^), and `gem install` wants a .gem file...

These are the contents of my unpacked gem:

```
AUTHORS       ChangeLog     NEWS          Rakefile      extconf.rb    pkg-config.rb src           test-unit
COPYING       GPL           README        doc           misc          samples       test
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it as a plugin? Most gems have a git URI's you can use and do something like:

```
./script/plugin install abc
```

Comment: This kind of worked actually :D I did "ruby extconf.rb; make; make install;" and it was installed XD
Thank you.